# images is not rendered in the browser(Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load a local image in my Nav component and in the landing page.

So this is what I've done so far:

```js
const LandingScreen = ()=>{

    return(
        <div>
           <img src ={'../Images/auction.jpg' } style={{width:100, height:100}} />
        </div>
    )

};

export default LandingScreen;
```

and this is my App component:

```js
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from './Components/Footer/Footer';
import './bootstrap.css';
import Register from './Screens/RegisterScreen/Register';
import Login from './Screens/LoginScreen/Login';
import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import LandingScreen from './Screens/LandingScreen';

const App = ()=> {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header/>
      <Routes className ="front">
        <Route path="/" element={<LandingScreen/>} exact/>
        <Route path ="/register" element ={<Register/>}/>
        <Route path ="/login" element ={<Login/>}/>
      </Routes>
      <Footer/>
    </Router>
     
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is the result that I am getting in the browser:
[How the image appear in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW8Xz.png)

Comment: Perhaps show the rendered HTML IN the question rather than some picture that many will never view/visit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to CRA documentation you should import you image first, then use it in your img tag

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/